# How to eat a virus without being split?

Tags: agar.io

I see some cells eat the green virus, and the funny thing is that the cell doesn't split: they simply eat it and become bigger. How can I eat a virus without being split?

Answer (score 4):

The maximum number of times you can be split in agar.io is 16 (16 different parts). So if you are split into 16 parts and one of those parts is larger than the virus you are able to consume it. incidentally you gain mass from eating viruses even if you do split so it can be useful to do that if you are in a safe place.